# JavaFX - How To Process TableView Change Before Continuing Code?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, java-threads

I have a `TableView` whose data is refreshed when the user clicks a button. However, the database query used to get the data can take some time.

During the search, I wish to display the `TableView`'s placeholder (which is a `ProgressIndicator`:

```
// Add progress indicator while searching
ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(ProgressIndicator.INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
pi.setMaxHeight(tblCallRecordList.getHeight() / 2);
tblCallRecordList.setPlaceholder(pi);

// Clear the table data
searchResults.clear();
tblCallRecordList.setItems(searchResults);

// Run the new search
processSearch();
```

However, when running the program, the `TableView` is never changed and the `processSearch()` method runs right away, keeping the old data in the `TableView` until the search is completed.

If I comment out `processSearch()`, the placeholder is displayed just fine.

Is there some strange thread flow going on that I am missing?

Comment: You're running this on the FX Application Thread. So that thread will not be able to perform any of it's other responsibilities (repainting the UI, responding to user input, etc) until your `processSearch()` method finishes.

Comment: I am confused as to why it does not even process the code directly above the `processSearch()` call, though. Is the parent method processed in full before the UI can be updated as well?

Comment: It does process it. All you do is change some properties in some objects. The visual result of those changes won't appear in your UI until the FX Application Thread gets a chance to repaint the UI, which it can't do because you are making it busy getting stuff from your database (something the UI thread has no business doing at all).